# What's the significance of "T-16"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, moon-knight-2022

In episode 4 of *Moon Knight*,

> after being shot by Harrow, Marc wakes up in a mental institution.

There's a game of bingo going on, and at one point the caller says:

> Sweet Sixteen! 16-T -- or T-16!

"T-16" is not a valid bingo number, so I assume this is an Easter egg of some kind. However, I'm unsure what significance it may have.

What is the significance of "T-16"?

Comment: [Star Wars reference](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-16_skyhopper)

Comment: Most of the numbers called aren't valid for the letter and number combinations.

Comment: why is T-16 not a 'valid' bingo call? Is there a shot of the card in question that shows that isn't valid? Not enough of a gripe to downvote, but that's a real world assumption re: a show about - well...not reality ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell A valid bingo call can only begin with B, I, N, G, or O, denoting which column to check. There's a shot of one of the players' bingo cards (it's [also in the episode's poster](https://www.disneyplusinformer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Moon-Knight-Episode-4-Poster.jpg)) and it has "Bingo" printed clearly along the top. 16 *is* on the card, incidentally, but it's in the "O" column.

Comment: in our universe :) who's to say what is valid in that crazy mixed up world Marc is in at the moment

Comment: As noted, there is a shot of the Bingo card. My comment about the other numbers not being valid is that B only goes from 1-15, I from 16-30, etc, and most of the calls are nonsense like "I-77" or "B-22" that can't happen. Not all of them, but most that I could make out.

Comment: What were the other letter-numbers called out?  It's possible the easter egg is that they are supposed to spell out a different word/message.

Comment: Hmm, Okay, found [this](https://epicstream.com/article/moon-knight-episode-4-the-bingo-card-explained), which has a list of the numbers called out, they're hash/salad as far as any word/message goes, but the author claims that each of the callouts refers to an issues of the Moon Knight comics.  I find that a bit sketchy myself, but perhaps someone else can confirm/explian that connection better.

Answer (score 14):

### TL;DR, T-16 is nonsense in both US and British Bingo, but the letter is purely an aesthetic/arbitrary item, so it shouldn't matter for a Bingo game

To answer the most immediate question, I don't know of anything in the *Moon Knight* mythology that ties into T-16, and I am in agreement with ShadowRanger that the most likely call-out would be to the *Star Wars* landspeeder. That said, I can address a bit of the aspect of Bingo rules and how they might apply.

As was noted in the comment, there was a promo image of the Bingo card, which looks like it matches what shows up in the episode.

[image: Image of the Bingo card]

As a trained Bingo caller, there's a lot wrong with this card. United States [Bingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_card) numbers range from 1-75 with each letter assigned to a set of 15. B goes from 1-15, I from 16-30, and so on. The letter assignment is purely aesthetic, to simplify people checking multiple cards (playing four cards is the minimum where I call, and some players were operating north of 64 cards at a time. Columns mean they only have to check a fifth of their numbers, fewer for the N column that has the free space). I will note that, as a caller, stating the wrong letter does not change anything since it is the number that is being checked, but it will get you heckled.

As you may note here, the numbers exceed 75, and are in the wrong columns. This might be partially explained if what we're seeing is a mix of Marc and Steven's minds because UK Bingo (also called Housie) uses numbers from 1-90, albeit on a 3x9 card (with each column having 10 numbers possible) rather than a 5x5 card.

[image: Image of a British Bingo card]

I haven't found any reference to UK Bingo callers using letters, but it's won by getting all 5 numbers in a row (no diagonals, verticals, four corners, big diamonds, or other patterns), which does match how Marc wins, having the last number called, and Bingo not announced until after the caller states the number (most Bingo halls will show a preview of the number before it is called to give people a chance to quickly check their cards to decrease the risk of someone missing Bingo being called since it usually must be on the last number called, particularly in money games). The promo image doesn't show the "2" daubed, but that generally is not required either, only having that winning card. The displayed card still could be a valid Housie result, since it looks like both 83 and 86 (which would both be in the eighth column, and therefore couldn't be on the same winning row) are daubed for the win, assuming that we're reading the card for a US Bingo win (although arguably, any set of 5 daubed numbers on the card could correspond to a valid Housie win if they're from a different range of 10).

### Inconsistencies could just be in his head, or the caller's

The incorrect Bingo card, and the use of incorrect letter and number combinations could simply be because Marc is only familiar with Bingo on a surface level. Much like how, if you asked someone who doesn't play chess to make up a board position, they're likely to create positions that couldn't actually exist due to how the pieces move and interact, it's possible that he just knows that Bingo involves letters and numbers, and he doesn't know how they correlate, or what range the numbers can use. Similarly, the caller, who might be a fellow inmate at the asylum, might be confused and assigning random letters or misreading the ball (An uppercase T looks a lot like the uppercase I that would be on the 16 ball, particularly if you're holding it such that your finger covers part of the ball), or they might just be pulling the letters and numbers out of thin air.

Comment: Ten years in and we finally get the deep-dive on bingo we’ve all been waiting for.

Comment: How do you "play" Bingo? Aren't you just checking off the boxes?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yeah, mostly it is mechanical with the only skill part being how many cards you can play comfortably within the time limit. Kind of like a lot of forms of timed Solitaire, really.

Comment: Housie Housie ? Is the 2nd Housie implied?  In the converse manner of the 2nd Wagga in Wagga Wagga being silent?

Comment: 86 and 88?  I think you mean the 83 in the left-column, 2nd row from the bottom, i.e. the row with the 2.  (Zoom way in, you can see that some of the fully black number extends into the blue dot, so it's *not* an 88 with the blue obscuring view of the black ink.)

Comment: Though it's a very informative answer, it doesn't actually answer the question. OP himself already established that it isn't a valid bingo number, and asked if there's another significance to T-16

Comment: @IvoBeckers: That is fair. I can't disagree with ShadowRanger that the only common Disney reference would be to the airspeeder.

Comment: Also odd that they would use a US-style 5x5 Bingo card, when the show is set in the UK.  Maybe you can't blame the American writers for not knowing that, but you'd think that someone would've noticed, since there are many Brits in the cast.  (Maybe not the crew - since it appears to have not been filmed in the UK at all, despite being largely set there.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: It is much more recognizable to US audiences, and Marc would likely be more familiar with the 5x5 cards (although honestly, if he'd never played seriously, he might not realize that the columns are tied to specific ranges of numbers). FWIW, most of the show is filmed in Budapest.

Comment: Yeah, I *almost* said it was filmed in the UK since it's set there, but then I looked it up.  Doesn't mean there *weren't* Brits in the crew I suppose, and I have no idea what version of Bingo (if any) is played in Hungary, but it must've been a deliberate choice to use a US card, and I don't know if it's just about the audience.  Nobody complained about James Bond playing Baccarat despite that being almost unheard of in American casinos.  You should be able to figure out enough to understand what's going on just by watching the film...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - the show starts in the UK, but Marc isn't from the UK. He's also clearly hallucinating or something along those lines and there are already dozens of non-sequiters in the scene. There's no reason to think the bingo card is a 'mistake'. Which was also my argument for the entire topic of 'valid' call - it's a fever dream. There's nothing 'valid' happening at all in the entire seqeunce. It's not real (in-universe. I'm not meaning to say the whole 'its just a tv show 'it's not real' statement)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: It definitely checks all my boxes... BINGO!!!

Answer (score 9):

Likely a throwaway reference to [the T-16 airspeeder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-16_skyhopper) from Star Wars; I haven't rewatched Star Wars in years, but I still clearly remember Luke telling a fellow pilot (who did not believe anyone could hit the 2m exhaust port on the Death Star) "I used to bullseye womp rats in my T-16 back home. They're not much bigger than two meters." Presumably throwaway references like that are expected to be recognized by a non-trivial fraction of their viewers. Disney owns all the IP, so why not cross-reference within their properties?

Given the number involved couldn't possibly show up on a Bingo card (and several other numbers are also nonsensical), I have to assume the game was either run by someone making random references rather than actually drawing normally, or it was implying the observer was in fact losing their sanity and hearing nonsense, either of which makes sense in the context of a mental institution.

Answer (score 1):

T-16 may be a reference to [the QNB-T16 truth serum](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/QNB-T16_Truth_Serum) from *Agents of Shield*.

> "This is QNB-T16, it's the top-shelf martini of sodium thiopental. It's a brand new and extremely potent truth drug. Don't worry, the effects only last about an hour." -Phil Coulson to Skye

Comment: Sure, or the kind of tram that Stan Lee used to ride to work. Is there any reason to think it's one or the other, or something else entirely?

Comment: Seems slightly more reasonable than the *Star Wars* reference since it's also Marvel (and one interpretation of the asylum scene is that it's Marc discovering truths about himself). ^_^ Maybe, even further reference, that that serum is supposedly a fake meant to put Skye at ease.

Comment: It's also categorically stated later that there was no truth serum. It was a ruse to convince Sky to trust them.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Although, IIRC, the person telling her that was Agent Grant Ward, who is a lying liar... :-D

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are the most probable, I would also like to point out that the caller does say "16 t" as well. The Skoda 16 T is a Polish train that is also called the Elektra.